# ORA-30929: ORDER SIBLINGS BY clause not allowed here

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-order-by, hierarchical-data

I am trying to write a SQL to show a hierarchical pattern. My first attempt was good with a single data, as the following SQL works.

```
SELECT CONCAT (LPAD (' ',LEVEL*3-3), M.MODULE) MODULE,M.ABBREVIATION,M.PARENT 
FROM    MRS_CUSTOM.CL_MODULES M
CONNECT BY PRIOR M.ABBREVIATION = M.parent
START WITH M.PARENT IS NULL
ORDER SIBLINGS BY M.MODULE;
```

This sql will show the following:

```
Admissions  ADMIS   
   Admissions Correspondence    ADMCO   ADMIS
   Agent Interface to Applicant Portal  ADAIAP  ADMIS
   Applicant Portal ADMP    ADMIS
      Statistics    APSTAT  ADMP
   My.Application Portal    MYAP    ADMIS
   Precedents   ADMIS_PRD   ADMIS
   Selection Process Management SPM ADMIS
Advanced Standing   ADVSTG  
   Precedents   ADVSTG_PRD  ADVSTG
Archive Module  AM
```

Now I need to append to this

```
    select (CONCAT (LPAD (' ',LEVEL*3-3), M.MODULE)) 
    MODULE,M.ABBREVIATION,M.PARENT,count(distinct(RS.REPORT_ID)) as 
    NUM_REPORTS,count(distinct(MP.DB_ROLE)) as NUM_ROLES 
    from MRS_CUSTOM.CL_MODULES M, MRS_CUSTOM.CL_MODULE_PRIVS MP, MRS_CUSTOM.CL_REPORT_SPECS RS
    where M.ABBREVIATION = RS.MODULE(+) and
    M.ABBREVIATION = MP.ABBREVIATION(+)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR M.ABBREVIATION = M.parent
    START WITH M.PARENT IS NULL
    group by M.ABBREVIATION, M.MODULE, M.PARENT
   ORDER SIBLINGS BY M.MODULE;
```

but I get error

```
ORA-30929: ORDER SIBLINGS BY clause not allowed here
```

Comment: `ORDER BY col1, col2, ...`

Comment: If I change to following:select (CONCAT (LPAD (' ',LEVEL*3-3), M.MODULE)) 
    MODULE,M.ABBREVIATION,M.PARENT,count(distinct(RS.REPORT_ID)) as 
    NUM_REPORTS,count(distinct(MP.DB_ROLE)) as NUM_ROLES 
    from MRS_CUSTOM.CL_MODULES M, MRS_CUSTOM.CL_MODULE_PRIVS MP, MRS_CUSTOM.CL_REPORT_SPECS RS
    where M.ABBREVIATION = RS.MODULE(+) and
    M.ABBREVIATION = MP.ABBREVIATION(+)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR M.ABBREVIATION = M.parent
    START WITH M.PARENT IS NULL
    group by M.ABBREVIATION, M.MODULE, M.PARENT
   ORDER BY M.MODULE;
   
error: 
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: You lost the GROUP BY.

Comment: select (CONCAT (LPAD (' ',LEVEL*3-3), M.MODULE)) 
    MODULE,M.ABBREVIATION,M.PARENT,count(distinct(RS.REPORT_ID)) as 
    NUM_REPORTS,count(distinct(MP.DB_ROLE)) as NUM_ROLES 
    from MRS_CUSTOM.CL_MODULES M, MRS_CUSTOM.CL_MODULE_PRIVS MP, MRS_CUSTOM.CL_REPORT_SPECS RS
    where M.ABBREVIATION = RS.MODULE(+) and
    M.ABBREVIATION = MP.ABBREVIATION(+)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR M.ABBREVIATION = M.parent
    START WITH M.PARENT IS NULL
    **group by M.ABBREVIATION, M.MODULE, M.PARENT**
   ORDER BY M.MODULE;

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to format. the group by is there.

Comment: You should add new information to the question as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63525287/edit), and format it; particularly code which is hard to read as comments. Your `group by` is using `M.MODULE` but the select list has `CONCAT (LPAD (' ',LEVEL*3-3), M.MODULE)`, which is causing the ORA-00979.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the join first, and then perform the hierarchical query on the result of the join:

```
SELECT CONCAT (LPAD (' ',LEVEL*3-3), M.MODULE) MODULE, M.ABBREVIATION, M.PARENT,
  M.NUM_REPORTS, M.NUM_ROLES
FROM (
  select M.MODULE, M.ABBREVIATION, M.PARENT,
    count(distinct(RS.REPORT_ID)) as NUM_REPORTS,
    count(distinct(MP.DB_ROLE)) as NUM_ROLES 
  from MRS_CUSTOM.CL_MODULES M
  left join MRS_CUSTOM.CL_REPORT_SPECS RS
  on RS.MODULE = M.ABBREVIATION
  left join MRS_CUSTOM.CL_MODULE_PRIVS MP
  on MP.ABBREVIATION = M.ABBREVIATION
  group by M.ABBREVIATION, M.MODULE, M.PARENT
) M
CONNECT BY PRIOR M.ABBREVIATION = M.parent
START WITH M.PARENT IS NULL
ORDER SIBLINGS BY M.MODULE;
```

I've switched to ANSI join syntax instead of Oracle's old-style joins.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=29b0635e69363b2dfe1b63de8b13ed4d) with some mad-up data.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that is what I was looking for.. Perfect